# using form clean(self) method to do validation

Tags: django, forms

this is my forms.py

What I wish to achieve is: before form gets saved- if there is admin_time present then execution_time should get replaced with admin_time.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(TaskForm, self).clean()
    start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
    end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')
    if start_date and end_date:
        if start_date >= end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("'End date' must be after 'Start date'"))
    return cleaned_data

    execution_time = self.cleaned_data['execution_time']
    admin_time = self.cleaned_data['admin_time']
    if admin_time:
        execution_time=admin_time
        cleaned_data.update(execution_time)
    cleaned_data.update(execution_time)
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: I would do this in your view, not your form. You clean method should be just for verifying the data in your form, not manipulating it.

Comment: I have done this in view but in that case i had to give the same code twice in createview class and updateview class. To avoid code repetition, thought of doing the same in forms.py

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a mixin for your views that takes care of this and can be used in multiple places:

```
class FooMixin(object):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        if self.object.admin_time:
            self.object.execution_time = self.object.admin_time
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

class MyCreateView(FooMixin, CreateView):
    pass

class MyUpdateView(FooMixin, UpdateView):
    pass
```